# Difference between HTML5 API and Phonegap API

Tags: html, cordova

I'm working with hybrid mobile application, where I wanted to save the contact to the device contact list.
I followed the Phonegap Api documentation. I was suprised to see Phonegap and HTML5 both uses the navigator object,
As per my understanding, both the api uses the same navigator object. So, how Phonegap Api is different from the HTML5 Api?

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to say exactly how they are different b/c it depends on which part of the API you're talking about and for which platform/browser.  The point of Phonegap is to use the HTML5 api in a way that you can build a single web app and then compile it to a native ios, android, ... app.  Mostly, the use of the phonegap api allows you to interact with the phone's api at a lower level than the HTML 5 api will allow.  Like getting access to the contacts or the device's sensors.  However, as browser support for HTML 5 evolves there is less and less functional ability you gain using phonegap.